# With Chef, how do I output the knife.rb settings its using?

Tags: debugging, chef-infra, knife

I'm using Chef knife and getting

```
ERROR: Could not find cookbook xyz in your cookbook path, skipping it
ERROR: Failed to upload 1 cookbook.
```

Looking at the knife.rb for the project and it looks like the cookbook path is right. How do I output what the knife command thinks the cookbook path is and where it thinks its getting that value from?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `knife config` plugin recently to see what knife sees:

http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2012/03/25/knife-config-plugin/

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Knife looks for a knife.rb file in `~/.chef/` and if it doesn't find one there, it will look in `./.chef/`. I'm not sure Knife offers a `printenv` equivalent, but you can always pass in `-c, --config CONFIG` to fix the upload problem.